# Vue.js "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: vue.js

For some weird reason, one of my project views stop working with the next error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Even though the code is right:

```html
<template>
  <v-layout wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>Conversation</v-flex>
    <v-flex xs12>Textarea</v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'chat',
};
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's highly unlikely the code in your question causes the error. Could you please show more of the error message? A screenshot from your browser console would probably be best

Comment: Which line is the error coming from? Check the source map if there is one.

Comment: I just added a screenshot @Phil

Comment: Does 1.js exist? Usually that error happens when trying to load a file that doesn’t exist and the result is an HTML error document which of course starts with <

Comment: There is no such file @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Then the problem isn’t in your Vue code but in other parts (Webpack? Script tags?)

Comment: Looks like you've got a misconfiguration in your Webpack chunks names and what vue-router is trying to [lazy-load](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html). Can you please show your route definition?